# Go from wide dataframe to a dataframe with listcolumns

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a 500Mb file in a wide format (132 columns wide) where six of the columns are variables describing an instance at time 1 to 16 (96 columns) and 36 of them are non-varying. I would like to change the datastructure so that I have a listcolumn for each of these instances and a separate column for non-varying info. The variable names for the time-instances are uniquely given by the names ending with "1".

```
library(tidyverse)
a<-data_frame(id=c("A","B","C"),
              const82=c("1952","1960","1970"),
              const6=as.Date(today()-c(1:3)),
              var1=c(1:3),
              z21=c(letters[1:3]),
              o31=c(11:13),
              m41=c(LETTERS[11:13]),
              var2=c(4:6),
              z22=c(letters[4:6]),
              o32=c(20:22),
              m42=c(LETTERS[7:9]))
```

So I tried:

```
gather(a, ... = dplyr::contains(ends_with("1"))) %>% nest(-id,-const81,-const6)
```

But I believe `contains` is not vectorized so that I cannot loop over all variables ending with "1". Furthermore, just like Group_by can be used for input to nest I believe it would be great to have a function that "nested the gathered columns".

Jumping from the tidyverse to data.table, I can

```
a_long<-melt(setDT(a), id=c("id","const82","const6"),
                 measure=patterns(c("^var\\d","^z2\\d","^o3\\d","^m4\\d")), 
                 value.name=vary<-c("var","z2","o3","m4"),
                 variable.name="num")%>%
 nest(... = num:m4,.key=instance)
```

which is more laborious than I was hoping for, but gets me halt the way. Now if I want to add another listcolumn for the constant variables, I cannot use nest anymore.

```
a_long%>% nest(-id,-instance)
Error in grouped_indices_impl(groups$data, groups$groups) : 
  cannot group column instance, of class 'list'
```

So-

1. How can I do this easily?
2. I would believe that these listcolumns would save memory from the Object in that less information is duplicated in the dataframe - but does it?

Desired datastructure - but the steps seem unnecessarily complicated:

```
a_long %>% select(1:3) %>% nest(-id,.key = const) %>% left_join(a_long) %>% select(-const82,-const6)
```

Comment: can you please share expected output based on your input data?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
gather(a,variable,values,ends_with("1")) %>% nest(-id,-const82,-const6)
# # A tibble: 3 × 4
#      id const82     const6             data
#   <chr>   <chr>     <date>           <list>
# 1     A    1952 2017-04-08 <tibble [4 × 6]>
# 2     B    1960 2017-04-07 <tibble [4 × 6]>
# 3     C    1970 2017-04-06 <tibble [4 × 6]>
```

and when you need to use characters as names in a dplyr function, usually there is a `_` version, like `gather_`

```
a %>% gather_("variable", "values",str_subset(colnames(.),"1+$")) %>% 
  nest(-id,-const82,-const6)
```